# Explain this JavaScript Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Explain this JavaScript Recursion what exactly happens when 0<0 expression does eval for foo(3)?
function-foo returns console.log("test")
Is it that console.log() passed in return statement is unusual?
Is it that the array has two 0's for indices 3 and 4 because foo evals 0 twice because once i-1 reaches 1-1 recursive call should be foo(0) yes?
But continues but console.log is being called twice where foo() recursion call is hoisted between the two what difference does order make here?
I'm not making sense of why exactly these are results

```js
let ar = [];

function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return console.log("test");

  ar.push(i);
  console.log(i, Boolean(i<0));
  foo(i - 1);
  ar.push(i);
  console.log(i, Boolean(i<0));
}

foo(3)
console.log('ar=', JSON.stringify( ar ))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your recursive code for `foo(3)` do:

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0) return   // stop recursive call
  ar.push(i)          // first push
  foo(i - 1)          // recursive call
  ar.push(i)          // second push
}
```

```js
ar.push(3)                // ar = [3]         ==== firsts push
    ar.push(2)            // ar = [3,2]
        ar.push(1)        // ar = [3,2,1]
            ar.push(0)    // ar = [3,2,1,0]
                return    // i == -1 , (i<0) is true => no pushS, no foo(i - 1)
            ar.push(0)    // ar = [3,2,1,0,0]  === seconds push
        ar.push(1)        // ar = [3,2,1,0,0,1]
    ar.push(2)            // ar = [3,2,1,0,0,1,2]
ar.push(3)                // ar = [3,2,1,0,0,1,2,3]
```

Comment: At some point i<0 must eval to true for foo(3) to return in if-statement
So if `Boolean(0<0)` evals to `false` then when does foo(3) eval to true to return?
Wouldn't only negative numbers make it true i.e `Boolean(-1<0)` evals to `true`?

Comment: Added `Boolean(i<0)` to check for cases when i<0 is true and looks like it never is?

Comment: @Jay , when i = -1 , (i<0) is true , an nothing more can be executed, as push a an other recursive call...